# C# variable in link to textbox

Tags: c#, variables, hyperlink, reference

Sorry, new to C# and I tried to find on the internet but I couldn't.
It's probably very simple for you but what I am trying to do is this:

```
for (i = 1; intCOUNTRIES > i; i++)
    {
        LC = inputCOUNTRY[i].Text;
        strCountryName = Country(LC);
        strCountries += strCountryName + ", ";  
    }
```

where the inputCOUNTRY[i].Text; changes with the for loop so it take the text from each textbox and then moves on to the next.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Are their multiples `TextBox` with `intCOUNTRIES` name?

Comment: Yes I have like 20 TextBoxes named inputCOUNTRY1, inputCOUNTRY2 etc. etc.
   Adil:  the problem is I don't know what the right syntax is to make it switch to the next textbox by each loop (I'm used to Visual Basic language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find your textbox in your container like this:

```
var pnlMain = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel(); // replace with your container (where your textboxes exists)
for (i = 1; intCOUNTRIES > i; i++)
{
   LC = ((TextBox)pnlMain.Controls.Find("inputCOUNTRY" + i)[0]).Text;
   strCountryName = Country(LC);
   strCountries += strCountryName + ", ";  
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it says 
Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: try this `((TextBox)pnlMain.Controls.Find("inputCOUNTRY" + i)[0]).Text`